# JS/Jquery: Initiate window resize without actually resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a very specific problem that presented itself recently (right before our planned launch day tomorrow) and I am not completely sure how to solve it. I have built our website of an HTML-template with my modest front-end skills and we are very pleased with it. However, I can't seem to solve this.

The problem:
I have a filter system that allows a user to filter articles that are presented on a page. A user can even fill in this filter on the home page, direct to the page with the articles and have the filter applied. However, if then the filter is broadened (less strict) and new articles present itself, the pictures do not show up. Found out this is the case because the flexslider behind it has to be initialized again which happens on a window load (e.g. when the window is resized). The function that controls the initialization of the flexslider is in an external js file and I am not sure whether I can call on it from my own custom.js file, so I am thinking of just calling a resize/reload window function to active it.

The question:
Can I run a resize window function (or something that activates the flexslider) without hindering user experience (more specifically, without ACTUALLY resizing/reloading the window)? I will run this on a change in the filter.

I know this is a very specific question but hopefully somebody can help me out.

Take care!

p.s. it would be ideal if I could run the actual function that loads the flexslider but this is located in an external js file.

EDIT:
Briefly some additional info. If I go straight to the article page, it has no filter active and thus shows all articles, if I then start flipping through the filter, all is good. It is however only if I arrive from the homepage with a set filter that the problems arise. You then arrive on the article page which shows only the articles that are within the boundaries, and when the filter is taken away it has problems loading the images of the new articles showing up. As if it had not loaded these because they were not open on window load the first time.

Comment: Can you tell us the name of the external js you'r using ?

Comment: Try to trigger the `resize` event... See if it really breaks user experience. The event will be triggered... But maybe it will not be "noticable" to the user. Try `$(window).trigger("resize");` If so, you'll have to call the function that instanciate the slider. It may need to be destroyed first...

Comment: Concerning your p.s.: I'm not sure I follow why can't you call a function in an external js file. You didn't specify what "flexslider" you're using, but it would be not at all unusual for such a library to offer some sort of refresh method in its public API.

Comment: @seifeddineBesbes: I think that is [FlexSlider](https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider)

Comment: you can rerun the actual function and i believe it will work for you.
Or like @doldt said i'am sure that contains a refresh function.
http://flexslider.woothemes.com/dynamic-carousel-min-max.html

Comment: Hey!

Thanks for the rapid feedback. A refresh function you say? And this should be in the same js file as the flexslider function is in? So the external file that I am talking about is: https://nomadr.nl/js/functions.js 

It contains much more than the slider. If I could initiate the flexslider function that is in this js file, from within another js file (my custom.js), that would be amazing.

Comment: Managed to fix it by delaying the function that loads in the filter values when the page loads. Thanks for all the help! Take care

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger a resize event by creating a new event and passing it into the [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) command on `window`. There's a [nice guide here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events). You'll want the type of event to be `resize`, since that's what it's listening for.

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))
```

This will work for events that were added via jQuery as well as events added via `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it after all by delaying the function that drops the filter values into my inputs so it loads in all images initially before applying the filter. It happens at such speed it's hardly noticeable.

Also, I did try to initiate a window resize function, it did work without actually resizing anything, but unfortunately the images did not load in properly (overlap and such).

Anyway, it has been solved. Thanks for all the input!